# Logstase parse and format date for ElasticSearch index

Tags: date, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

My elasticsearch index currently has an input of:

index    => "log-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

I have a field called logged_timestamp, in the format "05/05/2015:14:25:56 GMT", it seems to be  stored as 3 parts in the ES
[
"05/05/2015",
"14:25:56",
"GMT"
],

The logstash did this:

%{DATE_US:logged_timestamp}:%{TIME:logged_timestamp} %{DATA:logged_timestamp}

What I want to do is use the YYYY MM and dd from this captured field rather than the current one, as my index.

But i'm a bit stuck about how to do that, is it even possible to do inline? Or will I need to change how I capture that field in the input section first - i would rather avoid that? Date filter?

Comment: Use the date filter to populate the @timestamp field. The date filter requires the complete string to parse to be in a single (non-array) field, so you'll have to concatenate your three fields (which is doable in the grok expression).

Comment: yep, date filter did the trick.